# How to recursively find file, concatenate into one file and simultaneously delete the original file

Tags: find, rm, cat, recursive

As I understand it, I could use

`find . -name '*.txt' -exec cat {} \; > all.txt`

to concatenate all the text files in a directory, recursively throughout sub-directories, into a file called `all.txt`. The thing is, I don't have enough storage for `all.txt` and the original files. Is there a way to execute two commands, one after the other, so that I could delete the original file after concatenating it with `all.txt`?

Comment: text files usually compress quite well.  Using `gzip` or `bzip2` or your favorite compression algorithm you can probably make them all ~10% of their current size just by compressing them.  The problem with concatenating them together is, you don't know where one file ends and the other begins, and you lose all file metadata (name, owner, etc).  Only you know whether this matters in your use case, but I warn you not to discard that knowledge lightly.  Ideally you'd use `tar` to archive them (pretty much concatenation) and compress on the fly, if you have the space.  Otherwise, try compressing.

Comment: How big are these files? Can't you plug in a USB thumb drive to save them on while you are cleaning up your disk? Deleting as you go is fraught with danger (cf. the glob matching your output file problem as discussed in the answer below). And a +1 to @DanielFarrell's comment: a compressed tar archive is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

I think the most generalizable approach is to build a simple one-liner shell command to send to `find`:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec sh -c 'cat {} >> foobar && rm {}'
```

A side note: Your glob `*.txt` matched your output file, `all.txt`.  You'll avoid edge cases if the file you're appending too (`foobar` in my case) doesn't match your `-name` glob.  Just rename `foobar` later.

Comment: well considered - if you don't wnt to match all, try `-not -iname all.txt` should fix things up for you